# WebView in JavaFX does not show the webpage

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I'm working on a project. In that project I have to show a web page in JavaFX GUI. But it doesn't work out. It shows only a white window. My net connection is on.

Can anyone give suggestions what can I do to show a web page in my JavaFX GUI?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("HTML");
    stage.setWidth(500);
    stage.setHeight(500);
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    VBox root = new VBox();    
    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
    Hyperlink hpl = new Hyperlink("google.com");
    hpl.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
          webEngine.load("http://google.com");
      }
  });

    root.getChildren().addAll(hpl,browser);
    scene.setRoot(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

**Update:** I replaced " http:// google.com" to "https:// google.com " . Then it works perfectly.

Comment: Your code is correct. Make sure you are running correct Main class in your project, check IDE settings, try Clean-Build your project.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of Java's jdk

Comment: I use jdk 8.0 ,so ,what's the problem?

Comment: Are you on windows or linux? Linux packages javaFX separately.

Comment: @pdem Not as of Java 8.

Comment: @VGR, i'm speaking about openJDK, openJFX. I can garantee that on my Fedora, openJDK8 does not include Javafx. Anyway, the application shouldn't event start, that should not be the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code work perfectly on my computer when i click, google page is displayed.

You can also try to load it without clicking.

It must be a network problem, i guess the proxy: add theses arguments to your launch:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=youriphost
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
```

It's to be added on command line if you launch from command line, or vm arguments if you launch from eclipse.

Comment: thanks! I replaced " http:// google.com" to "https:// google.com " . Then it works perfectly. Though I don't know why!